# Using DataTable to compute a string expression

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8, datatable

I'm trying to use a `DataTable` to compute a string expression for a calculator application in C#. Here's the code snippet:

```
private void compute(String exp)
{
     DataTable dt = new DataTable();
     var v = dt.Compute(exp, "");
     ans.Text = v.ToString();
}
```

So I added a reference to `System.Data`, but then I started getting the following error:

> The type 'System.Xml.Serialization.IXmlSerializable' is defined in an
>   assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly
>   'System.Xml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089

To fix this, I tried adding `System.Xml` and then rebuilt the project, however the problem still persists.

**Note:** I'm adding references by going to Solution Explorer -> References -> .NET for Windows Phone. Is this the correct way of doing it?

Comment: You can not use DataTable or any other ADO.net library in windows phone application.

Comment: @Jaihind Oh! So is there an alternative to compute a string expression in Windows Phone?

Comment: Why not, You can use generic collations with your own logic to compute string expression in windows phone.

Answer (score 1):

While the `DataTable` class is not in `Silverlight`, you can use `List`, `ObservableCollection`, etc. classes for the Rows you would find in the DataTable.  Then have each "row" be a class or structure you defined for the column definitions.  LINQ can be used to query your new "Table."

Please refer to [Here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/df273297-729d-4f57-a560-2f80410cce76/datatable-in-windows-phone-development)